# Lazy, Eager and Explicit loading is not working in Entity Framework 5

Tags: entity-framework

Department class:

```
public partial class Department
{
    public Department()
    {
        this.Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
    }

    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }

}
```

Course class:

```
public partial class Course
{
     public Course()
     {
         this.Enrollments = new HashSet<Enrollment>();
         this.People = new HashSet<Person>();
     }

     public int CourseID { get; set; }
     public string Title { get; set; }
     public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
     public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

}
```

Context:

lazy loading is enabled as below.

```
universityDBContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
universityDBContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
```

Lazy loading is not working in Entity Framework 5. Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Department
{
    public Department()
    {
        this.Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
        this.Students = new HashSet<Student>();
    }

    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Budget { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> InstructorID { get; set; }
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Course
{
    public Course()
    {
        this.Enrollments = new HashSet<Enrollment>();
        this.People = new HashSet<Person>();
    }

    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Credits { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public byte[] rowversion { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Department")]
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I edited my answer, the `ForeignKey` attribute should be above the `DepartmentID`

Comment: Well your models should be fine then, can you post the query you are doing?

Comment: masterEntities universityDBContext = new masterEntities();
            universityDBContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            universityDBContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
            var dep = universityDBContext.Departments;
            foreach (var course in dep)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

Comment: Every department can have multiple courses, how can you just select one course in `dep` and try to write it into console? Did you do a `SelectMany` beforehand or something? Edit: `var result = universityDBContext.Departments.SelectMany(d => d.Courses).ToList(); foreach(var course in result) Console.WriteLine(course.Title);` That should work normally

Comment: This code universityDBContext.Departments selects all departments as well as courses. This shud nt be the case. If lazy loading is implemented properly, Courses should be loaded only if the iteration is done on courses

Comment: using (var context = new UniversityDBContext())
            {
                var data = from i in context.Departments
                           select i;
                foreach (var i in data)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(i.Name);
                    foreach (var j in i.Courses)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(j.Title);
                    }
                }
            }

Comment: Hi Alex. If its possible can u please do a simple program in DB first approach implementing lazy loading using EF 5 and share the code. Tat wud be of grt help to me.

Comment: That is your problem I think, you iterate over your departments (then Entity framework thinks you don't need the courses) and only in the foreach you ask for the courses. For this approach you will have to work with eager loading (`.Include(dep => dep.Courses)`)

Comment: I want to implement lazy loading not eager loading.

Comment: lazy loading is working when EntityFramework.sqlserver.dll  is added. But if it is added, It wud be EF6 not EF5